Google Sheet why equal dont update when update something?
I have a custom function in Google Apps Script called combineSheets() that is supposed to combine data from multiple sheets in a Google Sheets document. However, I noticed that the function does not update automatically when there are changes in the sheets.
function combineSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const arrayData = [];
  const sheets = ss.getSheets()

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const sh = sheets[i];
    const sheetName = sh.getName()
    
    if (sheetName !== 'RESUMO' && sheetName !== '_BASE' && sheetName !== 'ESTADOS') {
      const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
      const sourceValues = sh.getRange('B2:I').getValues();
      arrayData.push(...sourceValues);
    }
  }

  return arrayData;
}

Array combine from multiple sheets
